# Android custom layout notification without white border

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

When I'm using NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle style with both big and usual custom content view, there are system notification UI for expand/collapse is visible: notification width is reduced to 320dp width in both modes, and 64dp height in collapsed mode. When I trying to not add this style, notification is displayed in big custom layout mode only without collapse possibility. Can I achieve behavior like this?
[image]